# Derive protocol specification from LabelledGeneric

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given a

```
sealed trait A
case class Foo(i: Int) extends A
case class Bar(s: String) extends A

sealed trait B
case class B1(a: A) extends B
case class B2(bs: String) extends B

LabelledGeneric[B]
```

is it possible to derive a specification for the resulting json generated by your favorite json lib? I would like to use said specification to generate Elm source code.

Comment: You can easily derive JSON serializers for sealed trait hierarchies with LabelledGeneric (which gives you a Coproduct for sealed traits that you recursively format), but I'm not sure if that's what you mean with "specification".  Take a look at [shapeless for mortals](https://github.com/fommil/shapeless-for-mortals/blob/master/json/src/main/scala/derived.scala) for an example in `coproductFormat`.